# Custom gesture to text selection on iOS

Tags: ios, text, uitextview, selection, gesture

How to implement a different gesture to select text in a UITextView or web view in iOS? For instance, after tapping in a button to "enable" text selection, the user would just drag over the text to select it, instead of using the default text selection of iOS. How can that be accomplished?

Comment: This you figure this out?